# What is the pixel per degree ratio for the Pi cam?

Tags: raspicam

Sensor resolution   2592 x 1944 pixels

Horizontal field of view    53.50 +/- 0.13 degrees

then horizontally,

pixel/degree = 2592/53.5  = 48.45

If I change my resolution to 720 x 1280 pixels,

what is my new pixel/degree ratio?

Comment: Interesting question, but are you sure the field of view is chaning? At the highest resolution you are using the entire sensor, making it seem like the FOV is larger. At HD the image is cropped and I suspect any thing lower is the same as HD FOV.

Comment: Ok, I haven't been able to test it, but if what you say is true the pi cam always has a 53 degrees horizontal field of view no matter the resolution. I got confused because the dimension of the image was changing.

Comment: The camera has a discrete set of modes that it operates in; most provide a full fov and use pixel binning where required to downscale. However, the one exception is that the 1080p mode does *not* provide full fov. Details can be found at the to of http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/fov.html